# Boss Battles in Sword Art Online

Tags: sword-art-online

Why were many stages and levels skipped in Sword Art Online.  You see that they start at level one in the first episode but then later they skip to higher levels.

Why did the makers skip levels?  Was it because it would take too long?

Comment: I hear it's slightly more convoluted in the visual novels, as it doesn't even stick to a single *arc* for the first chapter.

Answer (score 5):

SAO first started as story for writing competition. But it was too long, so author didn't enter the competition and instead published it on the web. After that, it gained lot of popularity so author continued. This implies he never planned to write more. Also, it is said he was quite young and it was his first work. It was later on turned into light novels.

It began with SAO part with first chapter being introduction and how they got stuck in game. Then next chapter skips 2 year forward and how Kirito clears the game.

The next chapters are side stories, that happen chronologically somewhere in those 2 years.

After that comes ALO and the rest.

So it is obvious there wont be any continuity, because author never wanted to write such a story. And like Ikzer said, he is rewriting/retconing the story with SAO:Progressive

Answer (score 3):

It has many reasons. First, in the original novels they are a little more explained, but not much, so even in that original script it was skipped. Perhaps in first place all that happens in-between was less interesting.

However, starting this year Reki Kawahara (the novel's author) has begun to write the spin-off: **Sword Art Online: Progressive**, that explains precisely all that happens in-between during the Aincrad storyarc.